Avarage bond distance as a function of time step in aimd
I am trying to reproduce a plot of average bond distance vs time steps in aimd for the compound Na2AgSb using the data from the paper "Decoupling thermoelectric transport coefficients of Dirac semimetal Na2AgSb with intrinsically ultralow lattice thermal conductivity" which can be found here:
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mtphys.2021.100560
After the completion of the vasp calculations I am trying to plot the average bond distance between Ag and Sb atoms using the XDATCAR file. I am trying to do this using vmd software but I am not sure how to do this, I am able to plot the distance between two atoms but as there are more than 2 atoms in the unit cell for the same species (here 4 atoms of Ag and 4 of Sb) I am confused how to plot the average distance as a function of time step. Any help is greatly appreciated as it is very important for me. Thank you in advance.
